# Double-slit experiment detector interference

Tags: double-slit-experiment, interference

In most of the explanation clips of the double-slit experiment, nobody talks about possible detector interference.

This is the only clip that I've found to explain that the detector doesn't cause interference with the photons, stating that the wave pattern disappeared only when they were collecting the data, and appeared back if they did not collect the data(detectors still on, but no magnetic tape to write the results to):

[Explained ! The Double Slit Experiment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LW6Mq352f0E)

Is this the truth?

Comment: Can you summarize the argument instead of linking to a video?  And what do you mean by "detector interference"?  You'll have to explain what that means.

Comment: The means of detecting interacts with the photon, so the photon will behave in a different way.

Comment: As presented in this naive fashion this is pure nonsense. Nature doesn't know what a magnetic tape is. It only knows the difference between open and closed systems and that has absolutely nothing to do with us recording vs. not recording something.

Comment: Yes, it's naive, nonsense, etc. But, what surprises me even more than this naive conclusion would be the fact that people want to demonstrate something when they are aware that their means of detecting, interfere with the experiment.

Comment: At least in his non-sense conclusion, the enviroment was always the same: detectors on, all the time. There's no experiment if you turn the detectors on/off, because the environment changes. How can a scientist ignore this fact and still consider that he has a viable experiment?

Comment: If you are getting your science from Youtube, you can simply not expect to be given correct information. What else do you want us to say?

Comment: I don't like this ironic comments, that's Thomas Campbell and I'm nobody. You can't just serve me the "your getting the science from Youtube". It's a conference, it's not some random dude posting his own backyard conclusions.

Comment: Anyway, his description left me perplex also, but what would leave me even more perplex would be the fact that a scientist would consider that he has the same environment conditions when turning the detectors on, as he does when he has them off.

Comment: What makes you think that Thomas Campbell, whoever that is supposed to be, is an important person in physics, or that he even knows physics properly?

Comment: CuriousOne, let's better focus on this direction, as it's a more constructive one: "Anyway, his description left me perplex also, but what would leave me even more perplex would be the fact that a scientist would consider that he has the same environment conditions when turning the detectors on, as he does when he has them off."

Comment: What I am perplexed by is that you would take anything that is on Youtube for an expression of science. :-)

Comment: I think that you should stop, because your comments are not useful to the discussion. I was reasonable, showing you a constructive direction to talk about, since we settled that the statement of the video is false, but you keep on writing ironies.

Comment: @CuriousOne You made your point.  Move on.

Comment: @garyp: No need to be unfriendly. Look up who this particular Thomas Campbell is and what he does for a living. A little skepticism goes a long way on the internet.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The part of the data collection and its consequences to the result of the experiment, as presented in the video you provided, seems to be wrong. At least it never happened the way, the speaker wants to make us believe.

Chapter from the Wikipedia Article about the [Double-slit experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment):

> ### "Which-way" experiments and the principle of complementarity
>
> A well-known thought experiment predicts that if particle detectors are
>   positioned at the slits, showing through which slit a photon goes, the
>   interference pattern will disappear.[ 2] This which-way experiment
>   illustrates the complementarity principle that photons can behave as
>   either particles or waves, but cannot be observed as both at the same
>   time.[33][34][35] Despite the importance of this gedanken in the
>   history of quantum mechanics (for example, see the discussion on
>   Einstein's version of this experiment), technically feasible
>   realizations of this experiment were not proposed until the 1970s.[36]
>   (Naive implementations of the textbook gedanken are not possible
>   because photons cannot be detected without absorbing the photon.)
>   Currently, multiple experiments have been performed illustrating
>   various aspects of complementarity.[37]
>
> An experiment performed in 1987 [38][39] produced results that
>   demonstrated that information could be obtained regarding which path a
>   particle had taken without destroying the interference altogether.
>   This showed the effect of measurements that disturbed the particles in
>   transit to a lesser degree and thereby influenced the interference
>   pattern only to a comparable extent. In other words, if one does not
>   insist that the method used to determine which slit each photon passes
>   through be completely reliable, one can still detect a (degraded)
>   interference pattern.[40]

[ 2] Feynman, Richard P.; Robert B. Leighton; Matthew Sands (1965). The Feynman Lectures on Physics, Vol. 3. US: Addison-Wesley. pp. 1.1–1.8. [ISBN 0201021188](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/0201021188).

[33] Harrison, David (2002). ["Complementarity and the Copenhagen Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics"](http://www.upscale.utoronto.ca/GeneralInterest/Harrison/Complementarity/CompCopen.html). UPSCALE. Dept. of Physics, U. of Toronto. Retrieved 2008-06-21.

[34] Cassidy, David (2008). ["Quantum Mechanics 1925–1927: Triumph of the Copenhagen Interpretation"](http://www.aip.org/history/heisenberg/p09.htm). Werner Heisenberg. American Institute of Physics. Retrieved 2008-06-21.

[35] Boscá Díaz-Pintado, María C. (29–31 March 2007). ["Updating the wave-particle duality"](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/archive/00003568/). 15th UK and European Meeting on the Foundations of Physics. Leeds, UK. Retrieved 2008-06-21.

[36] Bartell, L. (1980). "Complementarity in the double-slit experiment: On simple realizable systems for observing intermediate particle-wave behavior". Physical Review D 21 (6): 1698. Bibcode:[1980PhRvD..21.1698B](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1980PhRvD..21.1698B). [doi:10.1103/PhysRevD.21.1698](https://dx.doi.org/10.1103%2FPhysRevD.21.1698).

[37]Zeilinger, A. (1999). "Experiment and the foundations of quantum physics". Reviews of Modern Physics 71 (2): S288. Bibcode:[1999RvMPS..71..288Z](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1999RvMPS..71..288Z). [doi:10.1103/RevModPhys.71.S288](https://dx.doi.org/10.1103%2FRevModPhys.71.S288).

[38] P. Mittelstaedt; A. Prieur; R. Schieder (1987). "Unsharp particle-wave duality in a photon split-beam experiment". Foundations of Physics 17 (9): 891–903. Bibcode:[1987FoPh...17..891M](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1987FoPh...17..891M). [doi:10.1007/BF00734319](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007%2FBF00734319).

[39] D.M. Greenberger and A. Yasin, "Simultaneous wave and particle knowledge in a neutron interferometer", Physics Letters A 128, 391–4 (1988).

[40] Wootters, W. K.; Zurek, W. H. (1979). ["Complementarity in the double-slit experiment: Quantum nonseparability and a quantitative statement of Bohr's principle"](https://elearning.physik.uni-frankfurt.de/data/FB13-PhysikOnline/lm_data/lm_740/res/files/file_1855/wootters-zurek.pdf) (PDF). Phys. Rev. D 19 (473–484). Bibcode:[1979PhRvD..19..473W](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1979PhRvD..19..473W). [doi:10.1103/PhysRevD.19.473](https://dx.doi.org/10.1103%2FPhysRevD.19.473). Retrieved 5 February 2014.

Comment: This is the correct answer, it never happened that way. This leads to the next question, why would you consider detectors on/off as having the same environment conditions.

Comment: We have to remember that we are talking about the detectors at the slits. Back when the Gedankenexperiment was proposed it was unknown how these detectors could look like. So if you have to pick out a proposed "photon fly by" detector of [37-39] and discuss the properties of this proposal.